# performance wise difference between inner join, nested query and natural join?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables created with following codes in MySQL 5.6

```
create table color(color_id int auto_increment primary key,
                   color varchar(10));
```

and

```
create table flower(id int auto_increment primary key,
                    name varchar(20),
                    color_id int,
                    constraint fk_color foreign key references color(color_id));
```

and then I inserted some rows in color then in flower.

then I queried

1)

```
   select flower.name, color.color from flower, color where
   flower.color_id=color.color_id;
```

2)

```
   select name,(select color from color where color_id=flower.color_id) color from flower;
```

3)

```
   select flower.name, color.color from color natural join flower;
```

4)

```
   select flower.name, color.color from flower natural join color;
```

All the queries gave me same result.

Which query is fastest and most efficient (nested query or inner join or natural join) and why specially among nested query and inner join?

what practice should we opt for querying?

whats the difference between the last two queries?

Comment: read about [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execution-plan-information.html) in MySql documentation.

Comment: whats the difference between the last two queries?: Some optimizers will choose different ways of executing a query based on the order of the tables in the from clause.

Comment: @Zohar : thanks for telling me about explain. It is quite a very useful tool. I tried using explain before the queries but the I was unable to use the Output of explain and explain extended to compare the performance. Could you also provide me with something that could tell me about how to use that outputs. and thanks one again.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Don't over think it. Say what you mean and mean what you say.  Simpler is usually faster.  Use primary and foreign keys. Use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are *not* the same.  The proper way to express what you want is either:

```
select flower.name, color.color
from flower join
     color
     on flower.color_id = color.color_id;
```

or:

```
select flower.name, color.color
from flower join
     color
     using (color_id);
```

And, for this query, you want an index on `color(color_id)` for best performance.  An index on `flower(color_id)` would also work, but is a bit more counterintuitive.

Here are comments on each of your versions (which I have numbered).

The first uses an archaic `join` syntax, which has been out-of-date for over two decades.  Time to move on and start using more modern forms, including explicit `join`s.  However, this should have no impact whatsoever on performance in comparison to the equivalent `inner join`.

The second is really a `left outer join`.  This uses a correlated subquery and can be the best approach, under some circumstances.  In this case, it should have the same performance, but there are fewer choices for optimization.

The third and the fourth are equivalent.  Kudos for using modern `join` syntax.  Now that I've said that, just avoid `natural join`.  Unfortunately, it does not use foreign key information defined for the tables.  Instead, it relies on columns having the same name.  Even though I design my tables to have primary keys and foreign keys with the same name, I *never* use natural join.  Depending on naming conventions means that a column such as `size` or `price` or `CreatedAt` would cause the `join` to do something other than what I intend.  Always use `on` or `using`.